# Sending content to the clipboard via a Bash script

Tags: clipboard, xclip

If I do `echo foo | xclip -i` in the terminal and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, I get `foo`.

But instead, if I write a file,

#### bar.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo bar | xclip -i
```

and run `./bar.sh` in the terminal, the clipboard content doesn't become "bar" as I would expect.

Why? And how do I make it do to so?

I managed to do it changing the line `echo bar | xclip -i` to `echo bar | xclip -selection c`, but why does this way work and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the command

```
echo bar | xclip -i
```

`xclip` stores the text in its `primary` register, which is accessible with the middle mouse button.  from `man xclip`

> -selection
>                 specify which X selection to use, options are "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" for XA_SECONDARY or "clipboard"  for
>                 XA_CLIPBOARD

When you use

```
echo bar | xclip -selection c
```

`bar` is being captured in xclip's `clipboard` register - I'm guessing `c` is an alias for `clipboard`.
Its strange the `echo bar | xclip -i` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> command worked - It doesnt for me. I wonder if you had `foo` in your clipboard from a previous command?